# How are parameters passed to knockout functions?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

For this binding :

```
<a data-bind='click: $root.thisValue '>
```

The corresponding knockout function takes a 'link' as a parameter :

```
this.thisValue = function(link) {
```

How is the 'link' parameter set ? It does'nt seem to be set within the data binding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not the element, its the data context associated with the element

http://jsfiddle.net/FpYkS/

```
ViewModel = function() {
    this.data = "data";        
}

ViewModel.prototype = {
    handle: function(item) {
        console.log(item.data);
    }
};
```

Comment: is this correct : ?  for function 'function(link)' knockout js is implicitly populating the 'link' parameter using the data parameter. The data parameter is set by knockout js to the value in the binding : '$root.thisValue'

Comment: If you are in a foreach binding loop and do root.myFunction the item passed to the function will be the element in the array